# Adding Price value to form and calculating

Tags: php, forms

So I have looked around here and havent seen something that can help. Basically I have a form that works great. The form gets submitted to a review and from the review page you can send it  off. What I am trying to do is get a "Price Total" on the review page. What I need to happen is add a value to sets of drop down items and multiply them to a the number of check boxes marked in a section. The link to the Fiddle will show what I am trying to do.

Example: how many Praxis PIs checked times their shaft selection.

```
<div id="leftDriver">
    <!-- Start Form -->
    <form action="reviewLeft.php" method="post" id="order">
        <!-- This is the club photos -->
        <div class="clubPhotos">
            <div class="club">
                <img src="clubs/img/praxispi.png" class="clubPhoto" /> <span class="clubTitle">Praxis PI</span>
 <span class="clubSub">Low Launch 9.5</span>

                <input type="checkbox" id="clubCheckbox4" class="clubCheckbox" name="DriverType" value="Praxis PI Low Launch 9.5" />
            </div>
            <div class="club">
                <img src="clubs/img/praxispi.png" class="clubPhoto" /> <span class="clubTitle">Praxis PI</span>
 <span class="clubSub">Mid-Low Launch 12.5</span>

                <input type="checkbox" id="clubCheckbox1" class="clubCheckbox" name="DriverType" value="Praxis PI Mid-Low Launch 12.5" />
            </div>
            <div class="club">
                <img src="clubs/img/praxispi.png" class="clubPhoto" /> <span class="clubTitle">Praxis PI</span>
 <span class="clubSub">Mid-High Launch 15.5</span>

                <input type="checkbox" id="clubCheckbox2" class="clubCheckbox" name="DriverType" value="Praxis PI Mid-High Launch 15.5" />
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- This is the driver order info -->
        <div class="clubForm"> <span class="heading">Club Specs</span>

            <select name="DriverLength" class="select">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Driver Length</option>
                <option value="47.5">47.5</option>
                <option value="47">47</option>
                <option value="46.5">46.5</option>
                <option value="46">46</option>
                <option value="45.5">45.5</option>
                <option value="45">45</option>
                <option value="44.5">44.5</option>
                <option value="44">44</option>
                <option value="43.5">43.5</option>
                <option value="43">43</option>
                <option value="42.5">42.5</option>
                <option value="42">42</option>
            </select>
            <select name="DriverShaft" class="select">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select Shaft</option>
                <option value="LE- light weight graphite weakest flex">LE- light weight graphite weakest flex</option>
                <option value="LW- Light weight graphite weak flex">LW- Light weight graphite weak flex</option>
                <option value="LM- Light weight graphite medium flex">LM- Light weight graphite medium flex</option>
                <option value="LR- Light weight graphite regular flex">LR- Light weight graphite regular flex</option>
                <option value="GR- Medium weight graphite regular flex">GR- Medium weight graphite regular flex</option>
                <option value="SS- Light weight graphite stiff flex">SS- Light weight graphite stiff flex (low torque)</option>
                <option value="TS- Medium weight graphite stiff flex">TS- Medium weight graphite stiff flex</option>
                <option value="SX- Light weight graphite X-stiff">SX- Light weight graphite X-stiff</option>
                <option value="KS- Light weight steel stiff flex">KS- Light weight steel stiff flex</option>
                <option value="KR- Light weight steel regular flex">KR- Light weight steel regular flex</option>
                <option value="DX- Heavy weight steel extra stiff">DX- Heavy weight steel extra stiff</option>
                <option value="DS- Heavy weight steel stiff flex">DS- Heavy weight steel stiff flex</option>
            </select>
            <select name="DriverPured" class="select">
                <option value="" selected="selected">PURE'd</option>
                <option value="high">High</option>
                <option value="low">Low</option>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
```

(note the JS attached to the fiddle is all for design and the orderform pop up)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/packytagliaferro/Hbchg/)

Comment: This should be in PHP or just Javascript? just to show the amount?...

please answer, so that I can check it out..

Comment: @daison12006013 doesnt really doesnt matter to me. I am familiar with both. All I am trying to get is the amounts from each section (if boxs checked times shaft price), added up at the end and displayed. Thanks. Cheers.